powerbi-client-react create visual
I have an embedded report in a react app and I am looking to create visuals following this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-add-visual#code-examples
I am running into "createVisual is not a function", is there a different approach that should be taken here?
const activePage: Page | undefined = await report.getActivePage();
activePage.createVisual('areaChart');


createVisual is a Power BI Report Authoring API. Make sure you Install the powerbi-report-authoring-npm package.
